# Angular 2 Material SideNav completely broken in Internet Explorer

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Is the sidenav material component for Ng2 supposed to be functioning and stable?
I see in IE11 it appears to be completely broken (I am on the SideNav screen, it's just so broken it fails to re-render, and remains displaying the previous screen):

[image]

https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview

Thanks,

Comment: You should report the issue [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/new) and not on stackoverflow.

Comment: It works fine for me in IE 11 for both in AM doc's demo and in my app.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of what I see on Windows 8.1, IE11 (latest)